# Append data to hidden column in HTML Table

Tags: css, html-table, append, show-hide

I have html table with hidden column. `style='display:none'`. When I append data to it using:

```
 $(tbl).append().
```

The column header stays hidden, but rows are shown. Is there way to keep the whole column hidden while appending rows.

Comment: can you share demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving display:none to the rows, not to header only. Check if it needs to be !important.
Edit : You can also try to use text() or html() function instead of append. https://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: I am trying to see if there is a way for to to inherit setting from header.

Comment: Have you tried giving to table parent element {visibility: hidden;} ?

Comment: I will try. Thank You

Comment: I think it will work, both visibility hidden and display none to parent "table" tag.You give display none to an existing row. When jquery generates rows they will appear without your style.